# initialize std::array without copying/moving elements

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, copy-constructor, stdarray

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

class C {
private:
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    std::string c;
public:
    C(std::string a_, std::string b_, std::string c_) : a{a_},b{b_},c{c_} {}
    ~C(){};
    C(const C&) =delete;
    C(const C&&) =delete;
    const C& operator=(const C&) =delete;
    const C& operator=(const C&&) =delete;
};

std::array<C,2> array = {C("","",""),C("","","")};

int main()
{}
```

this won't compile (Android Studio with NDK and clang) with a "call to deleted constructor of c" error. I know that I can e.g. use a `std::vector` and `emplace_back()` to construct an element directly inside the container, but in my code I want to only use fixed-sized containers and non-copyable/moveable objects for optimization. I'm probably missing sth basic here, but isn't there a way to initialize the `std::array` without first having to construct the individual elements and then copy them there?

Comment: By the way you don't need to put those underscores in your parameter names. `C(std::string a, std::string b, std::string c) : a{a},b{b},c{c} {}` has no ambiguity issues and does what you expect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use brace enclosed initializers instead of temporary `c` objects:

```
std::array<c,2> array = {{{"",""},{"",""}}};
```

or

```
std::array<c,2> array{{{"",""},{"",""}}};
```

Comment: Is it a portable solution? I mean it depends on how std::array is implemented, it must contain exactly one element of type `T[N]`.

Comment: @marcinj I am pretty sure of it. Last time I checked the requirement was not that `std::array` contain exactly one element of type `T[N]`, but that it behave as if it did. There was a whole issue about whether the middle `{}` could be omitted, i.e. whether this should also be valid: `{{"",""}, {"",""}}`. That last thing may have changed since C++11.

Comment: I am asking because I was reading one SO where T.C. said that it is not guaranteed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669200/how-should-i-brace-initialize-an-stdarray-of-stdpairs#comment43754338_27669457 .

Comment: @marcinj For the above syntax to work, there is no need for a single data member requirement.

Answer (score 6):

It would become possible since C++17, from that for some specified cases [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is guaranteed.

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit
>   the copy- and move- constructors of class objects even if copy/move
>   constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects:
>
> - In initialization, if the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the
>     class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to
>     initialize the destination object:
>
>   ```
>   T x = T(T(T())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
>   ```

And for these cases, copy/move constructor is not required to be accessible.

> `When copy-elision takes place (until C++17)` `In those cases where
>   copy-elision is not guaranteed, if it takes place (since C++17)` and
>   the copy-/move-constructor is not called, it must be present and
>   accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the
>   program is ill-formed.

[LIVE](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oLY7gW5ds4zsyVxy)